# How to override finisher for form sysext in TYPO3 to add multiple email adresses?

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

i want to override the default finisher for forms system extension of TYPO3 to set multiple email addresses for recipient address
or adding a new field for more email recipients

the problem is, that multiple email adresses in the recipient address field are running into an ecception

> Address in mailbox given
>   [first@email.de,second@email.de] does not comply with
>   RFC 2822, 3.6.2.

I know, I can use the recipients email and one cc, so I got 2 email recipients, but I need more ;)

like this:

> mail1,mail2,mail3,…

thanks for help or links to get this done

Answer (score 0):

This very feature has been implemented with TYPO3v10 where you can now easily set multiple recipients (To, Reply-To, CC, BCC):

```yaml
recipients:
  first@example.org: First Recipient
  second@example.org: Second Recipient
```

See [Feature: #80420 - Allow multiple recipients in email finisher](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/10.0/Feature-80420-AllowMultipleRecipientsInEmailFinisher.html) for details.

Since this is a feature there is no backport to TYPO3v8 nor TYPO3v9. For these TYPO3 versions you should go with a custom finisher which replicates this feature.

Alternatively apply the following patch to the `typo3/cms-form` package and provide a suitable YAML form definition:

```
--- Classes/Domain/Finishers/EmailFinisher.php.orig 2017-03-24 11:02:40.080329372 +0100
+++ Classes/Domain/Finishers/EmailFinisher.php  2017-03-24 11:03:46.116432657 +0100
@@ -108,10 +108,12 @@
             throw new FinisherException('The option "senderAddress" must be set for the EmailFinisher.', 1327060210);
         }

+        $recipients = is_string($recipientAddress) ? [$recipientAddress => $recipientName] : $recipientAddress;
+
         $mail = $this->objectManager->get(MailMessage::class);

         $mail->setFrom([$senderAddress => $senderName])
-            ->setTo([$recipientAddress => $recipientName])
+            ->setTo($recipients)
             ->setSubject($subject);

         if (!empty($replyToAddress)) {
```

This will allow you to use an array for `recipientAddress`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also define the finisher twice:

For if you use TYPO3 9 and don't want to implement a custom finisher or patch the form extension :)

```
finishers:
  -
    options:
      subject: 'Form filled at website.com'
      recipientAddress: email1@receiver.nl
      recipientName: 'John Doe'
      senderAddress: info@website.com
      senderName: 'website.com'
      replyToAddress: ''
      carbonCopyAddress: 'ccemail1@receiver.nl'
      blindCarbonCopyAddress: bccemail1@receiver.nl
      format: html
      attachUploads: true
      translation:
        language: ''
    identifier: EmailToReceiver
  -
    options:
      subject: 'Form filled at website.com'
      recipientAddress: email2@receiver.nl
      recipientName: 'Manager'
      senderAddress: info@website.com
      senderName: 'website.com'
      replyToAddress: ''
      carbonCopyAddress: ''
      blindCarbonCopyAddress: ''
      format: html
      attachUploads: true
      translation:
        language: ''
    identifier: EmailToReceiver
```

p.s. Only possible through filesystem form code, not possible in the form builder editor in the backend